# Unir 2 SELECTS Oracle e como resultado 2 colunas com valores diferentes

Tags: php, oracle

Estou enfrentando um problema, eu possuo dois selects sql

```
select *
from web.demonstrativo_processados 
where nroempresa = 1
  and data between to_date('2018/01/01' , 'yyyy/mm/dd')
  and to_date('2018/12/31' , 'yyyy/mm/dd')
```

que me trás os valores do ano de 2018 e tenho este:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
select * 
from web.demonstrativo_processados 
where nroempresa = 1
  and data between to_date('2017/01/01' , 'yyyy/mm/dd')
  and to_date('2017/12/31' , 'yyyy/mm/dd')
```

Que retorna os valores de 2017.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria que viesse como resposta estas duas colunas, por isso preciso integrar os 2 selects.

Como estou usando o php e o google charts para gerar gráficos, iria me facilitar muito o trabalho.
gráfico que pretendo fazer

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado

WHILE DO MEU PHP

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Mês', '2017', '2018'],


          <?php

            include ("./conexao_local.php");

            $sql = "select * from web.demonstrativo_processados where nroempresa = 1 and data between to_date('2017/01/01' , 'yyyy/mm/dd') and to_date('2017/12/31' , 'yyyy/mm/dd')";
            $stmt = oci_parse($conexao, $sql);

              oci_execute($stmt);

          while (($array = oci_fetch_array($stmt, OCI_BOTH)) != false) {
           $valorvenda = $array["VLRVENDA"];


           $valorvenda1 = str_replace(",",".", $valorvenda);

           ?>                       


          ['Mês 2017',  <?php echo $valorvenda1 ?>,400],
         <?php } ?>
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          hAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
          vAxis: {minValue: 0}
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div_1'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div_1" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Qual dado você quer trazer de 2018 e de 2017, quantidade? ou todos os dados?

Comment: todos, faço o filtro no php

Comment: mas unindo as linhas pela data?

Comment: Por que separar os dados por coluna/ano se já tem campo data nos registros? Você terá vários campos nulos conforme quantidade de anos, e ainda dificultará o filtro no PHP. O ideal seria saber o campo referente ao valor que quer, e fazer um `COUNT`, `SUM`, etc, depois `GROUP BY`. Tente melhorar sua pergunta, inserir mais detalhes, pois ficou ampla.

Comment: Tem que somar o valor por ano? é isso? vc quer coluna ANO e coluna SOMA do VLRVENDA?

Comment: não precisa somar nada rbz, só quero que venha as duas colunas, sem soma sem nada, que ai eu pego lá no php e consigo gera o gráfico que botei na pergunta

Comment: [CHAT](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84968/unir-2-selects-oracle-e-como-resultado-2-colunas-com-valores-diferentes)

Answer (score 1):

Consegui fazer

```
select a.vlrvenda as venda2017, b.vlrvenda as venda2018
  from web.demonstrativo_processados a, web.demonstrativo_processados b
 where a.nroempresa = 1
   and a.data between to_date('2017/01/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') and
       to_date('2017/12/31', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
   and a.nroempresa = b.nroempresa
   and b.data between to_date('2018/01/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') and
       to_date('2018/12/31', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
   and to_char(trunc(a.data, 'MM'), 'MON') = to_char(trunc(b.data, 'MM'), 'MON')
```

Comment: Creio que poderia ser simplificado para :`SELECT SUM(CASE YEAR(data) = 2017 THEN VLRVENDA ELSE 0 END) as venda2017, SUM(CASE YEAR(data) = 2018 THEN VLRVENDA ELSE 0 END) as venda2018
FROM web.demonstrativo_processados
WHERE nroempresa = 1
  AND YEAR(data) = 2017 OR YEAR(data) = 2018; `.

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit #1

```
SELECT data, VLRVENDAS
FROM web.demonstrativo_processados 
WHERE nroempresa = 1 
AND data between to_date('2017/01/01' , 'yyyy/mm/dd') 
AND to_date('2018/12/31' , 'yyyy/mm/dd')
```

---

Com `UNION`:

```
select * from (
(
select ANO = '2018', * 
from web.demonstrativo_processados 
where nroempresa = 1 
and data between to_date('2018/01/01' , 'yyyy/mm/dd') 
and to_date('2018/12/31' , 'yyyy/mm/dd')
)
union all
(
select ANO = '2017', * 
from web.demonstrativo_processados 
where nroempresa = 1 
and data between to_date('2017/01/01' , 'yyyy/mm/dd') 
and to_date('2017/12/31' , 'yyyy/mm/dd')
) as aliastab
```

Com `OR` e `YEAR`:

```
select YEAR(data), * 
from web.demonstrativo_processados 
where nroempresa = 1 
and ( (data between to_date('2018/01/01' , 'yyyy/mm/dd') 
and to_date('2018/12/31' , 'yyyy/mm/dd')) 
OR (data between to_date('2017/01/01' , 'yyyy/mm/dd') 
and to_date('2017/12/31' , 'yyyy/mm/dd')) )
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84971/discussion-on-answer-by-rbz-unir-2-selects-oracle-e-como-resultado-2-colunas-com)

Comment: cara, eu não tenho reputação hehe como vou responder um chat :T

Answer (score 0):

Supondo que você quer calcular o total de 2018 e o total de 2019, segue o código
utilizando uma consulta para 2018 e outra para 2017.

```
  SELECT (select SUM(valor)
           from web.demonstrativo_processados 
           where nroempresa = 1
           and data between to_date('2018/01/01' , 'yyyy/mm/dd')
           and to_date('2018/12/31' , 'yyyy/mm/dd')) as Total2018
          ,(select SUM(valor)
           from web.demonstrativo_processados 
           where nroempresa = 1
           and data between to_date('2017/01/01' , 'yyyy/mm/dd')
           and to_date('2017/12/31' , 'yyyy/mm/dd')) as Total2017
```

Comment: não rola, olha as edições que fiz na pergunta

Comment: Edite com uma imagem de como você quer ver o resultado da tabela. Como ficará com essas duas colunas.

Comment: quero as duas colunas que circulei em azul

Comment: você tem dados de 2018 e 2017. Uma coluna vai ficar vazia se não for de 2018 e a outra se não for de 2017? poste o resultado que você deseja em formato de tabela.

Comment: cara, eu quero que apareça as duas colunas como resultado, uma contendo os valores de 2017 e na outra coluna os valores de 2018